# How to use ArrayList in Vala using Anjuta as IDE?

Tags: vala, anjuta

I've been trying to use Anjuta to start using Vala. It was working well until I tried to use an ArrayList. The Gee library doesn't seem to work in Anjuta; it seems to be working when I compiled it manually. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to add

```
--pkg gee-1.0
```

in src/Makefile.am under VALAFLAGS, then reconfigure and build.

So far, I experienced that I have to add any libraries I use there. Otherwise, it won't find the references.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I was looking around the other makefiles for that spot but missed this one.

Comment: So to get it all to work, the --pkg flag needs to be added in that makefile, and the library needs to be configured in the library list as well for the project.

Comment: Why is this not automatically taken care of when you do Project->Add Library?